# Can't read csv into Spark using spark_read_csv()

Tags: r, csv, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm trying to use `sparklyr` to read a csv file into R.  I can read the .csv into R just fine using `read.csv()`, but when I try to use `spark_read_csv()` it breaks down.

```
accidents <- spark_read_csv(sc, name = 'accidents', path = '/home/rstudio/R/Shiny/accident_all.csv')
```

However, when I attempt to execute this code I receive the following error:

> Error in as.hexmode(xx) : 'x' cannot be coerced to class "hexmode"

I haven't found much by Googling that error.  Can anyone shed some light onto what is going on here?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Not sure, honestly.  Will update if I figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, local `.csv` files can be read easily in Spark Data frame using `spark_read_csv()`. I have a `.csv` file in Documents directory and I have read it using the following code snippet. I thing there is no need to use `file://` prefix. Below is the snippet:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:/Spark/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/")
library(SparkR, lib.loc = "C:/Spark/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/R/lib")
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", spark_home = "C:/Spark/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/", version = "2.0.1")

Credit_tbl <- spark_read_csv(sc, name = "credit_data", path = "C:/Users/USER_NAME/Documents/Credit.csv", header = TRUE, delimiter = ",")
```

You can see the dataframe just by calling the object name `Credit_tbl`.
[image]